# MongoDB: what is this operator called?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I found my solution in an obscure comment, but I want to find the documentation. Does anyone know what this operator is called? It returns a single, matching nested document in an array using the query selector.

```
const userSubscriptions = await Subscriptions.findOne(
  {
    user: subscribeTo._id,
    'subscriptions.user': subscriber._id
  },
  { 'subscriptions.$': 1 } // <-- *** what is this operator called? *** 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it doesn't have a "name", just the "positional $ operator".

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#projection